# Crafting Query Builder from SQL query

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

My goal is to create a search on the Order db, but some of them have relationships.

Is it possible to craft a query builder for this SQL query:

```php
SELECT * FROM `order` AS a
JOIN `users` AS b ON b.id = a.user_id
WHERE
LPAD(a.id,6,'0') LIKE '%keyword%'
OR
b.name LIKE '%keyword%'
OR
a.order_detail LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Now, I'm guessing to use `orWhere` for each criteria like:

```php
Order::where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
          $query->where(str_pad('Order.order_id', 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%')
                 ->orWhere('Order.order_detail', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
         //DO JOIN WITH USER TABLE HERE
         $query->where('Order.name', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%');
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at `LPAD()`?

Comment: ya I currently managed to get the SQL running:


`SELECT * FROM Order AS a
JOIN User AS b ON b.id = a.user_id
WHERE
LPAD(a.id,6,'0') LIKE '%000001%'
OR
b.name LIKE '%000001%'
OR
a.order_detail LIKE '%000001%'`

Comment: Can you replace that in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
Order::where(DB::raw("LPAD(id, 6, '0')"), 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%')
    ->orWhere('order_detail', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%')
    ->orWhereHas('user', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
         $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: I tried this and received the following error:

`{
        "status": "error",
        "message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::users does not exist."
    }`

Comment: You have to define the `users` relationship in the `Order` model.

Comment: Like this?

`public function customer() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'user_id'); }`

Comment: Yes. But `user()` instead of `customer()` ;-) I updated the query to `orWhereHas('user'`.

Comment: Yes, it works! But I'm still confused with the Query Builder syntax, like why do I have to put the model relationship function name in quote..Got to practice more on this. Thanks and i'm glad you're helping out, I accept your answer =)